# NSTextField placeholder text doesn't show unless editing ,What should I do?

Tags: macos, cocoa, placeholder, nstextfield

[image: editing] (Editing)        [image: not editing](Not Editing)

I have Subclass NSTextFieldCell and then override this method:

```
-(void)drawWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    NSRect customRect = cellFrame;
    customRect.origin.y = cellFrame.size.height - 1;
    customRect.origin.x = 0;
    NSColor *color = [NSColor grayColor];
    [color setFill];
    NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:customRect];
    [path fill];
    [super drawWithFrame:customRect inView:controlView];
}
```

At last I Set Class field of NSTextFieldCell in Interface Builder

Comment: There are two Screenshots editing and not editing above my question.This is my fist time to ask for help.I 'm not very familiar with how to ask for help here.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to do exactly, although your `NSTextFieldCell` is only showing the very top of it (1 pixel high to be exact).

```
customRect.origin.y = cellFrame.size.height - 22;
```

If you want to see the cell when you're not editing it then move it up (change 1 to 22, etc).

Comment: Thanks a lot，I just want to make my TextField only show it's bottom border like QQ's. I only found this way on internet. Is there a better way?